# Descarga excel subido en el servidor IIS ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Buenas tengo un problema estuve realizando un modulo para descargar excel y si funciona correctamente por la cual ahora estoy subiendo ese modulo en un `IIS` y si descarga pero cuando abre sale que el archivo esta dañado ademas se esta descargando en la carpeta de descargas ya que yo le habría puesto que se guarde en el disco `C://` y si me genera correcta en mi servidor local localhost

Este es mi código:

```
string query = "SP_ReporteExcel";
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ObtenerCadenaConexion()))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
    {
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 90000000;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("opt", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("fechainicio", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = txtFinicio.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("fechafin", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = txtFFin.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("rubro", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250).Value = dprAgencia.SelectedItem.Value;
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

            using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
            {
                sda.Fill(ds);

                //Set Name of DataTables.

                ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Recibos-Energia Electrica";
                ds.Tables[1].TableName = "Recibos-Agua Potable";

                using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
                {      
                    foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
                    {

                        DateTime d3 = DateTime.Parse(txtFinicio.Text);
                        string Mes = d3.ToString("MMMM");

                        DateTime d4 = DateTime.Parse(txtFinicio.Text);
                        string Anio = d4.ToString("yyyy");

                        wb.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
                        wb.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                        wb.Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.Black;
                        //wb.Style.Font.FontName = "calibri";
                        //wb.Style.Font.FontSize = 13;
                        wb.Style.Border.DiagonalBorderColor = XLColor.Red;
                        wb.Style.Border.RightBorderColor = XLColor.Red;
                        wb.Style.Border.LeftBorderColor = XLColor.Red;
                        wb.Style.Border.BottomBorderColor = XLColor.Red;

                        var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);

                        ws.Row(1).InsertRowsAbove(1);
                        ws.Cells("A2:H2").Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Black;
                        ws.Cells("A2:H2").Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.Yellow;

                        ws.Cells("D1:H1").Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Black;
                        ws.Cells("D1:H1").Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.Yellow;
                        string datetimeStringFileName = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", DateTime.Now);
                        ws.Range("D1:H1").Merge();

                        ws.Range("D1").Value = "Mes de " + Mes + " del " + Anio;
                        //ws.Cells("D1:H1").Value = "Mes";

                        //wb.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Black;
                        //wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);

                    }

                    Response.Clear();
                    Response.Buffer = true;
                    Response.Charset = "";

                    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"Reporte_Mensuales.xlsx\"");

                    using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        var aux = Guid.NewGuid();
                        wb.SaveAs("C:\\DatosSiga\\Logistica\\Reporte_Mensualess" + aux + ".xlsx");

                        MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                        Response.Flush();
                        Response.End();
                        Response.Redirect("FrmLogeo.aspx");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Lograste solucionarlo hermano?

Comment: Fredyfx si mi hermano , pero creo que me olvide dar una respuesta :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entendamos un poco lo que hace tu código, cuando haces esto `wb.SaveAs("C:\\DatosSiga...` y lo corres local seguramente te funciona bien porque el código toma los datos de donde existe actualmente la aplicación. Una vez que lo subes a un servidor, ahora tomará las rutas del servidor, esto nos conlleva a revisar permisos de lectura y escritura a otras carpetas por parte del usuario del **IIS**, ocasionando un mal funcionamiento porque el usuario de **IIS** no es un usuario administrador.

Otro punto que veo es que no es necesario guardar el archivo directamente en una ruta física, hagamoslo por medio de un `Stream` y luego descargamos ese *buffer* de datos:

```
Stream fs = new MemoryStream();
wb.SaveAs(fs);
fs.Position = 0;

MemoryStream stream = GetStream(ExcelWorkbook);

Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "Reporte_Mensualess" + aux + ".xlsx");
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
Response.End();
Response.Redirect("FrmLogeo.aspx");
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta pero una pregunta eso cuando ponga en generar donde se va guardar ese excel en la carpeta de descargas ? o en la ruta que yo he indicado ?

Comment: La carpeta Descargas es la predeterminada por el navegador, no estoy seguro que en cada equipo *cliente* se pueda guardar de forma pretederminada desde el código. Habrá que investigar la forma en que se pudiera hacer tal acción.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta colocando estos valores en el **webconfig** para que los tome el **IIS**

```
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <remove fileExtension=".xlsx" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".xlsx" mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Referencia: https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/define-mime-types-on-your-windowsiis-based-site/

Answer (score 0):

[Segun la documentacion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.writeto(v=vs.110).aspx):

> WriteTo Escribe todo el contenido del memory stream a otro memory
>   stream.

Estas utilizando [`WriteTo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.writeto(v=vs.110).aspx) en un `Stream` que esta vació.
Solo inicializas `MyMemoryStream` pero le escribes nada.

```
 using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
 {
       MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
       //...
 }
```

Por lo que cuando le escribes al response `MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);` en realidad no le escribes nada y por lo tanto el archivo se descarga dañado.

Debes de guardar el WorkBook como archivo y después leer el archivo y pasárselo a `MyMemoryStream`.

Ejemplo:

```
// aqui guardas el archivo...

//..

// Ahora lo lees
var excelBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("RutaDondeLoGuardaste");

using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(excelBytes))
 {
       MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
       //...
 }
```

Ya esa parte de guardar te la dejo a ti porque no se como se hace. Pero ya tienes la idea de porque el archivo descargado no funciona.